# How to grab datatable search key in cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp, datatable, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to apply data table for search data in cakephp. I already retrieve data using datatable. Now my problem is I am not able to grab `search value` query string. Below my tested code

data table code :

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "<?php echo $this->Url->build( [ 'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'Search' ] ); ?>",
            "ordering": false
} );
```

In controller I have tried below code to grab search key.

```
$search_key = $this->request->query('search[value]');
```

I am getting `null` in here. Data table send me query string like as below

```
search[value]:a
```

How I will grab it for next execution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$search_key = $this->request->query ['search']['value'];
```